# Why have all of the GIMP brushes disappeared?

Tags: gimp, tools, brush

All of the gimp brushes have, for some reason, disappeared and I don't know how to get them back.

The spot where you're supposed to see the name of the brush is just filled with *Clipboard*:

[image]

[image]

And the only tool that works now is the Ink tool. How should I fix this?

Comment: You can define brushes with the "Brushes" dialog (Shift+Ctrl+B).

Comment: @xenoid They are both present, though I am not able to find these directories. However, it has always been like this for me and before it had worked all right.

Comment: "both present" where? In Preferences>Folders? And you cannot find the directories in your file system? Then this is the explanation..

Answer (score 2):

Go to *Edit>Preferences>Folders>Brushes*. This should normally list two folders, one in your user folders, and one in the system folders. Are they both present? Can you find these directories and to do they contain files?

Btw, are there other things missing (standard patterns, gradients...)?